# Visual Studio Settings For Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, openmp

I'm trying to run the below c++ code in Visual Studio compiling with both Visual C++ and İntel Compiler. I'm setting the /Qopenmp option. Although the omp_get_max_threads() result is 2 the "printf("Running on multiple threads\n")" part is not printed twice.

This is the code:

```
#include <omp.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Starting Program!\n");
    int ntr;

    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(2);

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Running on multiple threads\n");
        ntr = omp_get_max_threads();
        printf("%d\n",ntr);
    }

    printf("Finished!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output

```
Starting Program!
Running on multiple threads
2
Finished!
```

What is wrong with this code or Visual Studio settings?

Comment: I can only speak to using MS Visual C++ (not Intel), but I see you apparently tried VS with both. One thing I do know is with MS Visual C++ openmp directives are ignored unless `/openmp` is enabled. If you go to `Project` menu, `Properties...` then under `Project Configurations`/`C/C++`/`Language` set `OpenMP` Support to `Yes` which effectively use `/openmp` switch. I don't know if that will work with Intel or not. I took your example code and ran it under MS VC++ with /openmp and it worked as expected. Didn't work without `/openmp`